# Cannot call container's endpoints with Heroku deployment

Tags: docker, heroku, dockerfile, gunicorn

I recently deployed a container on Heroku, but I can't seem to access the endpoints of the containerized application. The application uses flask_restful and is served by Gunicorn. Locally, I have no problem calling the container's endpoint by using its IP, but once it gets on Heroku nothing works.

This is how I start Gunicorn in my Dockerfile:

```
CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT wsgi:app
```

while the app's main is

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
   app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

On Heroku, the deployment of the container is successful and Gunicorn is able to start, but the endpoints cannot be called. These are Heroku's logs:

> 2021-10-23T08:42:20.385661+00:00 heroku[los.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c gunicorn\ --bind\ 0.0.0.0:\46659\ wsgi:app`
> 2021-10-23T08:42:21.045713+00:00 heroku[los.1]: State changed from starting to up
> 2021-10-23T08:42:21.270558+00:00 app[los.1]: [2021-10-23 08:42:21 +0000] [6] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
> 2021-10-23T08:42:21.271015+00:00 app[los.1]: [2021-10-23 08:42:21 +0000] [6] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:46659 (6)
> 2021-10-23T08:42:21.271099+00:00 app[los.1]: [2021-10-23 08:42:21 +0000] [6] [INFO] Using worker: sync
> 2021-10-23T08:42:21.274514+00:00 app[los.1]: [2021-10-23 08:42:21 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
> 2021-10-23T08:42:35.953189+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host= request_id=6a77117d-400b-4c17-bbe7-89163b166685 fwd="82.57.209.96" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong process type. Adding a Procfile with `web: gunicorn wsgi:app 0.0.0.0:$PORT` fixed the problem, as the web process type is the only one able to receive external traffic.

I suggest following [this](https://dev.to/ejach/how-to-deploy-a-python-flask-app-on-heroku-using-docker-mpc) guide.